# Material properties differing between vacuum or pressure filtration

Tags: materials, precipitation, filtering

During vacuum filtration of a very fine suspension, all solids that need to be removed are, but there is minimal solids loss. If the same material is pressure filtered (1-2 bar), desired solids removal is effective but the precipitated material matrix retains more liquid and other components entrained within. The thin slurry was tested and shown not to be a colloid.
What is the rationale for the filtered solids differing behaviour?

Comment: Are you sure you've got that the right way around?  One problem with filtering fines under vac is that the solvent (if a low boiler) starts to evaporate at the underside of the filter and precipitates impurities from the liquors and blinds the filter paper/cloth.

Comment: The solvent doesn't have that much time to evaporate in the filter under vacuum, especially if it's cold (this is normally carried out at zero degree Celsius or below). Both situations give rise to blinding eventually.